# What are the difference between the React codes below? Which one is most efficient or effective? Or are they practically the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I'm currently with a project and came up with two different set of codes and was wondering if there is a/are difference between the two.

ReactJS (latest version)

1.

```
columns.map(v => v.aggregate = (values) => values[0]);
```

2.

```
columns = columns.map( v => ({ 
            ...v,
            aggregate : (values) => values[0]
        }))
```

Expected result:

```
const columns = [
    {
        Header: 'ID',
        accessor: 'empid',
        shown: true,
        width: 130
    }, {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name',
        shown: true,
        aggregate: (values) => values[0],
        width: 130
    }, {
        Header: 'Age',
        accessor: 'age',
        shown: true,
        aggregate: (values) => values[0],
    }, {
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'email',
        shown: true,
        aggregate: (values) => values[0],
        width: 150
    },  {
        Header: 'Birthday',
        accessor: 'birthday',
        shown: true,
        aggregate: (values) => values[0],
        width: 150
    }
];
```

I will add this to ReactTable component with aggregation pivot by id.

Comment: One mutates the existing objects in the array, the other doesn't

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you're directly mutating each object. In the second example, you are using the spread operator first, so you're shallowly copying each object first instead of directly mutating it.

Comment: Thank you @JackBashford for replying!

Comment: Given the expected output, the two approaches will do the same thing without issues? How about performance or efficeincy?

Comment: The second one is less efficient because it copies the object - so for exceedingly large arrays (thousands) you're better off with the first option.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again sir. God bless you!

Comment: @randyk69 and for even better efficiency, you should not use `map` when don't want to create a new array. Just write a `for (const v of columns)` loop. And for even better efficiency, don't recreate many functions but simply assign the same to all of the objects: `function aggregate(values) { return values[0] } for (const v of columns) v.aggregate = aggregate;`.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi for your inputs. Noted on this.